# Razor script Intellisense without the script tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I load all my external script files async, when evrything is loaded, I have a callback that calls the remaining function.

```
<script>
    function executeLayoutInitialization()
    {
        // Execute basic functions...
        @RenderSection("deferredscripts", false)
    }
</script>
```

On some of my views (.cshtml), I load deferred scripts like this:

```
@section deferredscripts
{
    console.info("view loaded");
}
```

All of this works great, however, I lose JavaScript intellisense in doing so. To combat, I added script tag around the section. It looks like this:

```
<script>
@section deferredscripts
{
    console.info("view loaded");
}
</script>
```

This now gives me intellisense. However, I don't like that every view now has an empty script tag created. Also, ReSharper 2017.3.2 thinks it's not JS, so it throws error like "; expected" on something like `'@Url.Action("Load", "Action"){resharper_errorHere}'`

So, my question is, is there a way I can have JS intellisense on my razor view without specifying the script tag? Or, is there a better way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your `@RenderSection` at the layout level?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The `@section deferredscripts` depends on a `@RenderSection` within your page layout. Wrapping within the layout will ensure every instance is wrapped in a `script` tag.

Comment: Ah sorry about that, I edited my question. The RenderSection is inside a method, which is ALREADY inside a script tag. Everything works fine, the only problem is, on my other layout, I don't get intellisense unless I cover @section deferredscript with <script> tag as well. Which results in duplicate <script> tag.